# boost::interprocess::message_queue permission denied

Tags: c++, boost, ipc

So I have the following code with boost 1.47:

```
try
{
  m_messageQueue = boost::shared_ptr<boost::interprocess::message_queue>(
           new boost::interprocess::message_queue (
             boost::interprocess::open_or_create
             ,name.c_str()             //name
             ,numElements              //max message number
             ,sizeof(Message)          //max message size
             ));
}
catch(boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception &e)
{
  cerr << e.what();
}
```

where name="test_queue", numElements=100, and sizeof(Message)=256.

The output is:
Permission denied

If I run as user root, it will pass.  I can't figure out where it is trying to write to where it would have a permission error.  Looking at the boost code, shouldn't it just be in /tmp/boost_interprocess which any user would have access to create and write to?  Also, I noticed https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/4250, but this should be fixed now.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am on Centos 5.5. For me it was the need to set umask for the user running the queue to 022. 
After I set this in .bashrc all works as intended.